# Search - Is it possible to refine by top-level subsite?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, refiner

I'm on SharePoint Online and this is my site collection:
`https://something.sharepoint.com/sites/mySiteCollection`

Underneath this, I have the following major subsites:
`https://something.sharepoint.com/sites/mySiteCollection/About-Us`
`https://something.sharepoint.com/sites/mySiteCollection/Teams`
`https://something.sharepoint.com/sites/mySiteCollection/Policies`

Is it possible to set up something on the refinement panel of my search page so that I can refine by these three subsites (Just these three. Should not include subsites of these subsites.)

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, though you would have to write the JavaScript to do this yourself. You would refine on Path and look for your SubSites in the string.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of this. The string gets pretty complicated with other refiners involved. I ended up having different result sources instead and having those subsite choices in the dropdown on the searchbox.